# Firebase phone auth does not send code on real device - React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am newbie to React Native and working on Phone Authentication with RN & Firebase using **react-native-firebase** library which is super awesome!
My problem is that when i call "**signInWithPhoneNumber**" no SMS code is generated but the my mobile number is registered in the Firebase console. My code is below. Thank you

```
onLoginOrRegister = () => {
const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  .then((confirmResult) => {
    // This means that the SMS has been sent to the user
    // You need to:
    //   1) Save the `confirmResult` object to use later
    this.setState({ confirmResult });
    //   2) Hide the phone number form
    //   3) Show the verification code form
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const { code, message } = error;
    // For details of error codes, see the docs
    // The message contains the default Firebase string
    // representation of the error
  });
  }

onVerificationCode = () => {
const { confirmResult, verificationCode } = this.state;
confirmResult.confirm(verificationCode)
.then((user) => {
  // If you need to do anything with the user, do it here
  // The user will be logged in automatically by the
  // `onAuthStateChanged` listener we set up in App.js earlier
})
.catch((error) => {
  const { code, message } = error;
  // For details of error codes, see the docs
  // The message contains the default Firebase string
  // representation of the error
});
 }
```

Comment: did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it once, but I had to add a `WebView` on my App to render the required Google page which is responsible for sending and authenticate SMS code.

This is the code you must take as base for building your `WebView`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2016 Google Inc.
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Phone Authentication simple popup flow</title>

  <!-- Material Design Theming -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.orange-indigo.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">

  <!-- Header section containing title -->
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-color-text--white mdl-color--light-blue-700">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--8-col-desktop">
        <a href="/"><h3>Firebase Authentication</h3></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-grid">

      <!-- Container for the demo -->
      <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
        <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--light-blue-600 mdl-color-text--white">
          <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Phone number authentication simple popup flow</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
          <p>Sign in with your Phone number below.</p>

          <!-- Button that starts the sign-in flow -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" id="sign-in-button">Sign-in with Phone number</button>

          <!-- Button that handles sign-out -->
          <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" id="sign-out-button">Sign-out</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Container for the sign in status and user info -->
      <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
        <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--light-blue-600 mdl-color-text--white">
          <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">User sign-in status</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
          <!-- Container where we'll display the user details -->
          <div class="user-details-container">
            Firebase sign-in status: <span id="sign-in-status">Unknown</span>
            <div>Firebase auth <code>currentUser</code> object value:</div>
            <pre><code id="account-details">null</code></pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>

<!-- Import and configure the Firebase SDK -->
<!-- These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting -->
<!-- If you do not serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup -->
<script src="/__/firebase/4.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/4.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /**
   * Set up UI event listeners and registering Firebase auth listeners.
   */
  window.onload = function() {
    // Listening for auth state changes.
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        var uid = user.uid;
        var email = user.email;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        var phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
        var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var providerData = user.providerData;
        var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
      }
      updateSignInButtonUI();
      updateSignOutButtonUI();
      updateSignedInUserStatusUI();
    });
    // Event bindings.
    document.getElementById('sign-in-button').addEventListener('click', onSignInClick);
    document.getElementById('sign-out-button').addEventListener('click', onSignOutClick);
  };
  /**
   * Function called when clicking the Login/Logout button.
   */
  function onSignInClick() {
    window.open('/phone-simple-popup.html', '_blank', 'height=600px,width=450px,top=100px,left=100px');
  }
  /**
   * Signs out the user when the sign-out button is clicked.
   */
  function onSignOutClick() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
  /**
   * Updates the state of the Sign-in form.
   */
  function updateSignInButtonUI() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      document.getElementById('sign-in-button').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('sign-in-button').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
  /**
   * Updates the state of the Sign out button.
   */
  function updateSignOutButtonUI() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      document.getElementById('sign-out-button').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('sign-out-button').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  /**
   * Updates the Signed in user status panel.
   */
  function updateSignedInUserStatusUI() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
      document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
      document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify(user, null, '  ');
    } else {
      document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
      document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = 'null';
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/phone-simple.html

It must be uploaded to a web server.

Then, in your React Native component, you must call your HTML WebView as this:

```
      <WebView
        javaScriptEnabled
        domStorageEnabled
        injectedJavaScript={patchPostMessageJsCode}
        source={{uri: 'https://yourServerDomain.com/YourWebViewFile.html'}}
        onMessage={this.signupUser}
      />
```

All SMS send and validation will be handled by the HTML.

This is quite tricky and by the time I implemented, was the only solution I could find.

You can find more details in the official docs, looking for JavaScript implementation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Also this repo is very useful: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth

Hope it helps

Comment: hi is there any other solution to instead of webview?

Answer (score 0):

**I solve this issue by deleting a Facebook account from firebase auth containing a same number in it.**